# How to add events like onClick on SVG image placed over normal <img > tag in HTML code

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

/* here i just have an image with a svg over it */

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <body>
        <div>
          <img src="test.jpg" alt="Shirt Image" />
           <img   id="tt-mask" class="mask" src="mask11.png" alt="Mask Image" />
           <div   id="logo-mask" role="m ... z" ></div>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: You might want to tell us what your problem is and what you tried do far.

Comment: where is the svg picture/img element you are using ?

Comment: hi , the div with id logo-mask has a role attribute with svg i ve traced using inkskape. I dea is to colour the image on click . bit the svg part isnt taking any event

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just add a div wrapper around the svg element and put the click event on the div.